# Copy row to column in Mysql Trigger

Tags: mysql, triggers

I'm trying to create a trigger on my table. I need save old fields to another table's JSON column.

Can I do it ?

Comment: Yes, you can. Retrieve old values from `OLD` pseudotable, build needed JSON and insert into another table.

Comment: @Akina Thank you, I want to take all columns without writing "OLD.id" so Can I do like that ?

Comment: Noway. OLD is not a table and does not allow to use an asterisk as "all columns" placeholder.